# is there a way to use different heroku regions based on location under one domain?

Tags: heroku

I'm creating a socket.io app. I like to have one url that my app would connect to. I was thinking about using freegeoip.net and computing the distance away from each region and using the closest one.

what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will not allow you to have two apps in different regions pointing to the same domain.
The best way to achieve something like this is to proxy requests to a CDN like [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which will automatically serve requests from the closest location it has.